# Can not create a machine with Vagrant and Chef

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf

I'm trying to create a Ubuntu machine with Vagrant and Chef Solo. 
So, I've created a simple Vagrantfile and a simple recipe, just to test it.
But I'm facing with the following error message:

> Recipe Compile Error in
>   /tmp/vagrant-chef/71c53eb7bf7c3d22bf315b2652372569/cookbooks/teste/recipes/default.rb
>
> ==> default: NoMethodError
>   ==> default: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
>
> ==> default: Cookbook Trace:
>   ==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef/f7fdc686ea08792157234990dd67a042/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:33:in
>   from_file'
>   ==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef/71c53eb7bf7c3d22bf315b2652372569/cookbooks/teste/recipes/default.rb:3:in
>   `from_file'
>
> ==> default: Relevant File Content:
>   ==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/f7fdc686ea08792157234990dd67a042/cookbooks/apt/recipes/default.rb:
>
> ==> default:  26:  file '/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp' do
>   ==> default:  27:    owner 'root'
>   ==> default:  28:    group 'root'
>   ==> default:  29:    action :nothing
>   ==> default:  30:  end
>   ==> default:  31:
>   ==> default:  32:  # If compile_time_update run apt-get update at compile time
>   ==> default:  33>> if node['apt']['compile_time_update'] && apt_installed?
>   ==> default:  34:    apt_update('compile time') do
>   ==> default:  35:      frequency node['apt']['periodic_update_min_delay']
>   ==> default:  36:      ignore_failure true
>   ==> default:  37:    end.run_action(:periodic)
>   ==> default:  38:  end
>   ==> default:  39:
>   ==> default:  40:  apt_update 'periodic' do
>   ==> default:  41:    frequency node['apt']['periodic_update_min_delay']
>   ==> default:  42:  end

Below there are my files:

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = "./cookbooks/teste/Berksfile"

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
   chef.install = false
   chef.add_recipe "teste"
  end
end
```

**Berksfile**

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'java'
```

**default.rb**

```
include_recipe 'apt::default'
include_recipe 'java::default'
```

**attributes.rb**

```
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'openjdk'
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
default['java']['accept_license_agreement'] = true
```

**metadata.rb**

```
name 'teste'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures teste'
long_description 'Installs/Configures teste'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 12.1' if respond_to?(:chef_version)
```

**About my configuration:**

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.3.4
chef-client version: 13.4.19
berks version: 6.3.1
kitchen version: 1.17.0
inspec version: 1.36.1

Vagrant 2.0.1

macOS Sierra (10.12.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `depends 'apt'` and `depends 'java'` to the metadata of your cookbook. Then remove the `cookbook` lines in the Berksfile as they are redundant.

Comment: Why should I change it? It should work for the both way (Metadata or Berksfile), right? Anyway, after the changes I'm facing a new issue: _uninitialized constant Chef::Mixin::HomebrewUser_

Comment: No, it only works one way. chef-client only knows about dependencies from the metadata, so it didn't actually load the apt cookbook even though it was available because Berkshelf had downloaded it. Please start a new question for a new issue or ask in Slack.

Comment: Got it. But I'm using chef-solo, not chef-client. The behavior is the same? Another question is: when should I use Berksfile, then?

Comment: You still need a berksfile, but just with the `source` and `metadata` lines.